# Testing twilio api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

Let me first start of by saying that I'm a new person writing tests here, working with rails only for few weeks.
Writing a rspec test for my phone verification. Here is some code first :

```
User.stub(:create).and_return(@user)
@user.stub(:send_sms).with('foo').and_return('bar')

sign_in @user
visit home_path

click_link 'Telephone verification'
```

Now this is the method in my user that I want to stub and return arbitrary value without actually going into the real method :

```
def send_sms
    TWILIO_CLIENT.account.sms.messages.create(
      :from => TWILIO_SMS_NUMBER,
      :to => phone,
      :body => "Verification code is: #{sms_code}"
    )
  end
```

Am I doing even doing the right thing here? I'm not even sure, I read so much stuff on this topic, still confused.

Since I don't have TWILIO_CLIENT initialized for test environment I get this error when I save_and_open_page :

```
uninitialized constant User::TWILIO_CLIENT
```

And so I want to stub the send_sms method, is that the right thing to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't have TWILIO_CLIENT initialized for test environment

You'll need to define those constants somewhere. It should be as simple as:

```
TWILIO_CLIENT = double('twilio_client')
TWILIO_SMS_NUMBER = double('twilio_sms_number')
```

Now you can stub methods on the test doubles.

To stub the call itself, you can use `stub_chain`:

```
TWILIO_CLIENT.stub_chain(:account, :sms, :messages, :create)
```

While this should work, whenever you see `stub_chain` it suggests that you may want to refactor. In this case, you probably shouldn't be reaching into TWILIO_CLIENT and messing with its internals.